# Factory pattern with parameterized methods

Tags: java, code-duplication, factory-method

These are a set of services which all follow the same algorithm. Consumers call these services and the services send the request for the consumers to some backend system. The service interface is RESTful and the backend-end is SOAP. Because all of them follow the same pattern, we have an abstract class. The order of the methods is fixed, i.e. commonMethodOne needs to happen before commonMethodTwo, etc.

The concrete class will have to implement the two abstract methods as each service interface is different.

```
public abstract class CommonService<T1, T2, T3, T4> {

    public T4 getResponse(T1 request) {
        T2 backendRequest = transformClientRequestToBackendRequest(request);
        commonMethodOne(request);
        commonMethodTwo(request);
        T3 backendResponse = getBackendResponse(backendRequest);
        commonMethodThree(backendResponse);
        commonMethodFour(backendResponse);
        return transformBackendResponseToClientResponse(backendResponse);
    }

    public abstract T2 transformClientRequestToBackendRequest(T1 request);

    public abstract T4 transformBackendResponseToClientResponse(T3 backendResponse);

    public void commonMethodOne(T1 request) {
        //some code
    }

    public void commonMethodTwo(T1 request) {
        //some code
    }

    public void commonMethodThree(T3 backendResponse) {
        //some code
    }

    public void commonMethodFour(T3 backendResponse) {
        //some code
    }

    public T3 getBackendResponse(T2 backendRequest) {
        // call to backend system
    }
}
```

The issue is the following. 95% of the services will follow this pattern. However, a small percentage will need the client request in order to transform the backend response to the client response.

So the method:

`public abstract T4 transformBackendResponseToClientResponse(T3 backendResponse);`

would become:

`public abstract T4 transformBackendResponseToClientResponse(T1 clientRequest, T3 backendResponse);`

However, this is only applicable to a small subset of the services. So, I don't want to add another abstract method to 95% percent of the services or change the signature to keep one method as that would be a change to concrete classes. The other solution would be to have a parent abstract class that contains the common methods and two children abstract classes. Each one would have a different flavor of `transformBackendResponseToClientResponse`, but the `getResponse` would have to be repeated in each abstract class.

How can this be implemented without code duplication?

Answer (score 0):

One option could be using an additional interface in the mix for the ~5% scenarios.  That interface could look like below, and your concrete class would be defined as `extends CommonService implements LessCommonInterface`:

```
interface LessCommonInterface<T1, T3, T4> {
    T4 transformBackendResponseToClientResponse(T1 clientRequest, T3 backendResponse);
}
```

Another option could be to create a second abstract class that extends the first. This way, ~95% of your concrete classes would be defined as `extends CommonService`, and the ~5% would be defined as `extends LessCommonService`:

```
abstract class LessCommonService<T1, T2, T3, T4> extends CommonService {
    public abstract T4 transformBackendResponseToClientResponse(T1 clientRequest, T3 backendResponse);
}
```

Yet another option would be to use a single abstract class as you are currently doing, and change the signature for the 95% and 5% use cases to pass some kind of wrapper object that always contains a `T1` object and *sometimes* contains a `T3` object but this kind of code is messy and will probably create problems over time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java8+ you can use default method implementation. So a step by step will be
1. Extract interface from CommonService with all methods you're overriding something like

```
 interface ICommonService<T1, T2, T3, T4>{
       T2 transformClientRequestToBackendRequest(T1 request);
       T4 transformBackendResponseToClientResponse(T3 backendResponse);
       T4 transformBackendResponseToClientResponse(T1 clientRequest, T3 backendResponse);   
       default T4 transformBackendResponseToClientResponse(T1 clientRequest, T3 backendResponse) {
           return transformBackendResponseToClientResponse(clientRequest);
    }
    }
```

2. Mark you're abstract class as implementing interface. 95% will use default implementation other will use overriden version. Hope it helps